# Check feasibility of a system of integer linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm currently working on a very large integer linear programme which cannot be solved within any reasonable time.
The initial set of linear equations S={Ax<=b) is feasible. 
I want to add more constraints to this system and check whether these additional constraints render the problem infeasible. 
Is there an approach/algorithm that takes into account that the initial set is feasible and only checks the additions to the system?